# time complexity of following recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

Find out the time complexity (Big Oh Bound) of the recurrence `T(n) = T(⌊n⌋) + T(⌈n⌉) + 1`.

How the time complexity of this comes out to be `O(n)`??

Comment: Are you sure I don't forget coefficients somewhere e.g. coefficient `2` in `T(⌊n/2⌋)`? Your recurrence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This recurrence will never converge

Comment: But we have lower bound and upper bound also in its expression

Comment: @Luv: The upper bound and lower bound *might* change the value in the first call of T(n), but then `T(floor(n)) = T(floor(n)) + T(ceil(n)) + 1`, and as you see [and as reseter said] it will not converge. You must decrease the range in order of the recursion to converge

Comment: Those are floor and ceiling - not lower and upper bound.  If n = 5, you have T(5) = T(5) + T(5) + 1 which can never be true.  There has got to be a typo here.

Comment: DRVic: not exactly true, T(5) = 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably ment `T(n)=T(⌊n/2⌋)+ T(⌈n/2⌉) + 1`.

Lets calculate first few values of `T(n)`.

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = 3
T(3) = 5
T(4) = 7
```

We can guess that `T(n) = 2 * n - 1`.

Lets prove that by [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

Basis

```
T(1) = 1
T(2) = 3
T(3) = 5
T(4) = 7
```

Inductive step

```
T(2*n) = T(⌊2*n/2⌋)+ T(⌈2*n/2⌉) + 1  
   = T(⌊n⌋)+ T(⌈n⌉) + 1 
   = (2*n - 1) + (2*n - 1) + 1 
   = 4*n - 1
   = 2 * (2*n) - 1

T(2*n+1) = T(⌊(2*n+1)/2⌋)+ T(⌈(2*n+1)/2⌉) + 1
   = T(n)+ T(n+1) + 1
   = (2*n - 1) + (2*(n+1) - 1) + 1 = 
   = 4*n + 1 =
   = (2*n+1)*2 - 1
```

Since both the basis and the inductive step have been proved, it has now been proved by mathematical induction that T(n) holds for all natural 2*n - 1.

`T(n) = 2*n - 1 = O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently does not make sense. Since `n` is usually taken to be a natural number, then `n=⌊n⌋=⌈n⌉`. The recurrence then reads: break down a problem of size `n` into two problems of size `n` and spend time `1` doing that. The two new problems you just created will be split in turn, and so on- all you are doing is creating more work for yourself.